# Line plot with differently colored segments

Tags: python, plotly

Having something like the code below:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=index,
                         y=mr,
                         name='MR',
                         marker=dict(color=list(mrc)),
                         mode='markers'
                         ), row=1, col=1)
```

where `mr` and `mrc` is a `pandas.Series` with float and hex color values respectively, will generate the expected dots with the expected colors.

Is there a way to have the same thing, but with a line, instead of markers. So in this case the line would have different colors in different parts of it. As an example see the attached image where we go from `green` to `lime` in the same line trace.

[image]